# Wallet application using C and SQLite

Tags: c, sqlite

I built a straightforward program in C. It's just a STACK structure (first in, last out) that takes input from the user and stores it into the stack. After I close the program, all the data vanishes since I don't have a database implemented into the program. Even so, the program runs fine. It allocates memory according to the user's input, and I always validate every allocation.

In fact, my issue isn't concerning C code itself. It's the implementation of SQLite into the C code. Every `stack_node` has a **value (integer)**, **date (char)**, and **info (char)**. The wallet structure is the "middle-man" between the `stack_node` and the DB, and it has the same attributes plus an ID (integer autoincremented). What I'm trying to do is to as soon as the user inputs data (while the program is running) this data gets stored not only in the stack but also in the DB. After the user is done inputting data, I usually use `pop_stack()` to retrieve the data from the stack onto the screen, but since the data is stored in the DB, it makes more sense just to extract all data from the DB.

I don't get any compilation errors and the SQLite source files/header files are implemented correctly into the code. I know this because I'm using SQLite Studio ( SQLite GUI) and I see all the attributes from the wallet DB, but they are all empty.

So, that's my issue. I'm doing something wrong that causes the program to not store the data correctly into the DB.
--- Is it a waste of memory and running time for the program to create a stack, stack_node etc...to only after all that store the information in the DB? Should I just skip all that and program just for the DB? If so, how would I do that since I would eventually run into the same problem. I'm using the stack because I might have more control over what I can do with the data like adding the values, calculate average expenditure and so on.

**Mini Project Version** - *same functionality*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#define MAXB 1024

#define CREATE_TABLE_WALLET \
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wallet" \
    "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
    ",value INTEGER NOT NULL)"

typedef struct Wallet Wallet;

struct Wallet{
    int id;
    int value;
    Wallet * next;
};

typedef struct stack_node{
    int value;
    struct stack_node * next;
}stack_node;

typedef struct stack{
    int size;
    stack_node * top;
}stack;

stack * create_stack(){
    stack * s = malloc(sizeof * s);
    if(!s){
        perror("malloc-s");
        return NULL;
    }
    s->size=0;
    s->top=NULL;
    return s;
}

stack_node * push_stack(stack * s,int value){
    stack_node * n = malloc(sizeof * n);
    if(!n){
        perror("malloc-n");
        return NULL;
    }
    n->value=value;
    n->next=s->top;
    s->top=n;
    s->size++;
    return n;
}

stack_node * pop_stack(stack * s){
    if(s->size > 0){
        stack_node * node = s->top;
        s->top=s->top->next;
        return node;
        s->size--;
    }
    return NULL;
}

Wallet * newWallet(const Wallet * wallet){
    Wallet * w = (Wallet *)malloc(sizeof(Wallet));
    w->value = wallet->value;
    w->id=wallet->id;
    w->next = NULL;
    w->id=-1;
    return w;
}

int error(sqlite3 * db){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s \n",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return sqlite3_errcode(db);
}

void addData( sqlite3 * db, stack_node * node){
    if(node == NULL){
        return;
        }

    char sql[100];
    while(node != NULL){
        sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO wallet(value,date, info) VALUES (%d)",
                node->value);
        if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
            error(db);
            return;
        }
        node=node->next;
    }
}

int callback(void *ptr,int numbCol,char **valCell, char **nameCol){
    (void)ptr;
    int ix;
    for(ix=0; ix < numbCol ; ++ix){
        printf("%s: %s \n",nameCol[ix],valCell[ix]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void readDB(sqlite3 * db){
    sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM wallet", callback, NULL,NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    stack * s =  create_stack();
    stack_node * node = NULL;

    Wallet wallet;

    sqlite3 * db = NULL;
    const char * filenameDatabase = "C:/Users/ricar/Downloads/docs/C/trialszz/wall.db";

    ///open date base
    if(sqlite3_open(filenameDatabase,&db) != SQLITE_OK){
        error(db);
    }

    ///config DB
    if(sqlite3_exec(db, CREATE_TABLE_WALLET, NULL, NULL,NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
        return error(db);
    }

    for(;;){
        char buf[MAXB] = "";
        int value = 0;

        for(;;){
            fputs("\nenter value: ",stdout);
            if(fgets(buf,MAXB,stdin)){
                if(*buf == '\n'){
                    fputs("**input done**",stderr);
                    goto inputdone;
                }
                else if(sscanf(buf,"%d",&value) == 1)
                    break;
                else{
                    fputs("**invalid integer input**\n",stderr);
                }
            }
            else{
                fputs("**user canceled input** \n",stderr);
                goto inputdone;
            }
        }

        if(push_stack(s,value)){
                addData(db, node);
            }
    }
    inputdone:;


    puts("\n\n|-|-|STACK DATA|-|-|\n\n");
    readDB(db);

    /* while((node = pop_stack(s)) != NULL){
        printf("value: %2d \n",node->value);
        free(node);
    }
    free(s); */

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

**Complete Project**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#define MAXB 1024
#define MAXDT 64
#define MAXIF 128

#define CREATE_TABLE_WALLET \
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wallet" \
    "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
    ",value INTEGER NOT NULL"\
    ", date TEXT NOT NULL" \
    ", info TEXT NOT NULL)"

typedef struct Wallet Wallet;

struct Wallet{
    int id;
    int value;
    char date[64];
    char info[128];
    Wallet * next;
};

typedef struct stack_node{
    int value;
    char * date;
    char * info; 
    struct stack_node * next;
}stack_node;

typedef struct stack{
    int size;
    stack_node * top;
}stack;

stack * create_stack(){
    stack * s = malloc(sizeof * s);
    if(!s){
        perror("malloc-s");
        return NULL;
    }
    s->size=0;
    s->top=NULL;
    return s;
}

stack_node * push_stack(stack * s,int value,char * date,char * info){
    stack_node * n = malloc(sizeof * n);
    if(!n){
        perror("malloc-n");
        return NULL;
    }
    n->value=value;
    ///-------------
    n->date = malloc(strlen(date) + 1);
    if(!n->date){
        perror("malloc-date");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(n->date,date);
    ///-------------

    ///-------------
    n->info = malloc(strlen(info) + 1);
    if(!n->info){
        perror("malloc-info");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(n->info,info);
    ///-------------
    n->next=s->top;
    s->top=n;
    s->size++;
    return n;
}

stack_node * pop_stack(stack * s){
    if(s->size > 0){
        stack_node * node = s->top;
        s->top=s->top->next;
        return node;
        s->size--;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void free_node(stack_node * n){
    if(n->date && n->info)
        free(n->date);
        free(n->info);

    free(n);
}

void free_stack(stack * s){
    while(s->size > 0){
        stack_node * victim = s->top;
        s->top=s->top->next;
        free_node(victim);
        s->size--;
    }
    free(s);
}

Wallet * newWallet(const Wallet * wallet){
    Wallet * w = (Wallet *)malloc(sizeof(Wallet));
    strcpy(w->date,wallet->date);
    strcpy(w->info,wallet->info);
    w->value = wallet->value;
    w->id=wallet->id;
    w->next = NULL;
    w->id=-1;
    return w;
}

int error(sqlite3 * db){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s \n",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return sqlite3_errcode(db);
}

void addData( sqlite3 * db, stack_node * node){
    if(node == NULL){
        return;
        }

    char sql[100];
    while(node != NULL){
        sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO wallet(value,date, info) VALUES (%d,'%s','%s')",
                node->value,node->date,node->info);
        if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
            error(db);
            return;
        }
        node=node->next;
    }
}

int callback(void *ptr,int numbCol,char **valCell, char **nameCol){
    (void)ptr;
    int ix;
    for(ix=0; ix < numbCol ; ++ix){
        printf("%s: %s \n",nameCol[ix],valCell[ix]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void readDB(sqlite3 * db){
    sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM wallet", callback, NULL,NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    stack * s =  create_stack();
    stack_node * node = NULL;

    Wallet wallet;

    sqlite3 * db = NULL;
    const char * filenameDatabase = "C:/Users/ricar/Downloads/docs/C/trialszz/wall.db";

    ///open date base
    if(sqlite3_open(filenameDatabase,&db) != SQLITE_OK){
        error(db);
    }

    ///config DB
    if(sqlite3_exec(db, CREATE_TABLE_WALLET, NULL, NULL,NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
        return error(db);
    }


    for(;;){
        char buf[MAXB] = "";
        char date[MAXDT] = "";
        char info[MAXIF] = "";
        int value = 0;

        for(;;){
            fputs("\nenter value: ",stdout);
            if(fgets(buf,MAXB,stdin)){
                if(*buf == '\n'){
                    fputs("**input done**",stderr);
                    goto inputdone;
                }
                else if(sscanf(buf,"%d",&value) == 1)
                    break;
                else{
                    fputs("**invalid integer input**\n",stderr);
                }
            }
            else{
                fputs("**user canceled input** \n",stderr);
                goto inputdone;
            }
        }

        for(;;){
            fputs("enter date: ",stdout);
            if(fgets(date,MAXDT,stdin)){
                size_t lenDT = strlen(date);
                if(lenDT && date[lenDT - 1] == '\n'){
                    date[--lenDT] = 0;
                    if(lenDT)
                        break;
                    else
                        fputs("**empty-line**\n",stderr);
                    }
                    else if(lenDT == MAXDT -1){
                        fputs("**warning: string too long** \n",stderr);
                    }
            }
            else{
                fputs("**user canceled input**\n",stderr);
                goto inputdone;
            }
        }

        for(;;){
            fputs("enter INFO about value: ",stdout);
            if(fgets(info,MAXIF,stdin)){
                size_t lenIF = strlen(info);
                if(lenIF && info[lenIF - 1] == '\n'){
                    info[--lenIF] = 0;
                        if(lenIF)
                            break;
                        else
                            fputs("**empty-line**\n",stderr);
                }
                else if(lenIF == MAXIF - 1){
                    fputs("**warning: string too long**",stderr);
                }
            }
            else{
                fputs("**user canceled input**",stderr);
                goto inputdone;
            }
        }
        if(push_stack(s,value,date,info)){
                addData(db, node);
            }
    }
    inputdone:;


    puts("\n\n|-|-|STACK DATA|-|-|\n\n");
    readDB(db);

    /* while((node = pop_stack(s)) != NULL){
        printf("value: %2d  date: %s  info: %s  \n",node->value,node->date,node->info);
        free_node(node);
    }
    free_stack(s);   */

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

**Only SQLite code**
A few things to consider:
- This code works fine, but it takes pre-existing data from a .txt file and stores it in the SQLite DB -- if you delete the .txt file afterwards it won't affect the DB.
- If I want to display the data from the DB all I have to do is copy/paste the `callback()` and `readDB()` functions from the project's code.
- I don't like using a .txt file. I chose to use SQLite precisely because it's a serverless DB, and so you won't need to do a lot. You just put the source files into your project and that's that. Having said that, I tried to use the same concepts from this code to the project's code, but always getting the data from the user while the program is running, and not from a .txt file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

#define CREATE_TABLE_WALLET \
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wallet" \
    "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
    ", info TEXT NOT NULL " \
    ", value INTEGER NOT NULL)"

typedef struct Wallet Wallet;

struct Wallet{
    char info[100];
    int value;
    int id;
    Wallet * next;
};

void showList(const Wallet * list)
{
    if(list == NULL){
        printf("[empty-list]\n");
        return;
    }
    Wallet * ix = list;
    while(ix != NULL){
        printf("ID: %d; info: %s; value: %d \n",ix->id,ix->info,ix->value);
        ix=ix->next;
    }
}

Wallet * newWallet(const Wallet *wallet)
{
    Wallet * w = (Wallet *)malloc(sizeof(Wallet));
    strcpy(w->info,wallet->info);
    w->value=wallet->value;
    w->id=wallet->id;
    w->next = NULL;
    w->id = -1;
    return w;
}

void addWallet(Wallet ** list, const Wallet * wallet)
{
    if(list == NULL){
        return;
    }
    if(*list == NULL){
        *list = newWallet(wallet);
        return;
    }
    Wallet * ix = *list;
    while(ix->next != NULL){
        ix=ix->next;
    }
    ix->next=newWallet(wallet);
}

int error(sqlite3 * db)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s \n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return sqlite3_errcode(db);
}

void addData(const Wallet * list, sqlite3 * db)
{
    if(list == NULL){
        return;
    }
    Wallet * ix = list;
    char sql[100];
    while(ix != NULL){
        sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO wallet (info, value) VALUES ('%s', %d)", ix->info, ix->value);
        if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
            error(db);
            return;
        }
        ix=ix->next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE * file = NULL;
    Wallet wallet;
    Wallet * list = NULL;
    sqlite3 * db = NULL;
    const char * filenameDatabase = "C:/Users/ricar/Downloads/docs/C/123_sqlite3/wall.db";
    const char * filenameList = "C:/Users/ricar/Downloads/docs/C/123_sqlite3/data.txt";
    ///open DB
    if(sqlite3_open(filenameDatabase, &db) != SQLITE_OK){
        return error(db);
    }

    ///config DB
    if(sqlite3_exec(db, CREATE_TABLE_WALLET, NULL,NULL,NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
        return error(db);
    }

    ///read DB
    file = fopen(filenameList, "r");
    if(file ==  NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening file. \n");
        return ferror(file);
    }

    while(!feof(file)){
        fscanf(file, "%s%d",wallet.info,&wallet.value);
        addWallet(&list, &wallet);
    }
    fclose(file);

    ///showList(list);

    addData(list,db);///move data from .txt to .db

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you make a smaller [mcve]? Demonstrating creation and the (failing) filling with sample data should take fewer lines. It would improve your chances for helpful answers.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll leave the entire code for now while I work on it. There are indeed a lot of repetitive lines that could be taken out. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: The problem at heart appears to be writing to SQLite. Minimize the problem down without the stack code and see if you can prove you can write data of any sort into SQLite.

Comment: Got it. I'll do that now. Thanks!

Comment: Volomike, I followed your suggestion and added only the SQLite code to my question hoping to clarify my thought process.  I hope you or somebody else can help me out with this.  I really want it to work.

Comment: Print out the value of `sql` before executing it. And don't ignore what `error` tells you!

Comment: I used `fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",sql);` in the `addData()` function, but nothing happened. That means my node is getting to `addData()` as NULL, right? How can I fix this? Also, `error` doesn't print anything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on the [SQLite website](https://sqlite.org/cintro.html). I wasn't setting up my statements correctly. Although it's not absolutely necessary in order to store data in the DB, it is if you wanna store variables.

> The principal task of an SQL database engine is to evaluate SQL
>   statements of SQL. To accomplish this, the developer needs two
>   objects: 
>   * The database connection object: sqlite3 
>  * The prepared statement object: sqlite3_stmt

The function below does exactly that:

```
void putData(sqlite3 * db, stack * s,stack_node * node)
{
    node = s->top;
    s->top=s->top->next;
    sqlite3_stmt * stmt;
    int rc;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "insert into wallet (value, date, info) values (?1, ?2, ?3);", -1, &stmt, NULL);

    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, node->value);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, node->date, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, node->info, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
    error(db);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```